# How can I use JIRA to track Story Points per Developer on my team?

Tags: jira, scrum, jira-plugin, jira-agile

I need to provide some metrics on my Scrum team for management. The most important metric is how many story points are assigned to each member during a sprint. I would like to just assign them to the team in general, as that would be a better implementation of SCRUM, but unfortunately I can't do that.

Anyway, I have been looking for a dashboard gadget that will track how many points are assigned to each team member, how many story points are verified complete, and how many remain. So far the search (in Jira documentation, google, and stackoverflow) has yielded nothing. My current solution is to put all of the information in an excel spreadsheet. This works, but seeing how all other metrics are integrated into a Jira gadget or the like, I would really like this to be present on my board.

So again: Can I use JIRA gadgets to track story points per developer?

*Sorry if this is not the right community for this question, but searching JIRA in stackexchange brought me here.

Comment: I worked with a team that was forced by management to track story points per team member. The team members stopped helping each other out as any time not spent on their own stories was tracked as waste. The output of the team dropped considerably.

Comment: I couldn't agree more. It really encourages people to stop asking for help as well, because if someone else finishes their ticket then it looks like they missed their goal. It is a terrible system. Overwhelms less experienced members and encourages senior team members to overextend themselves by helping others without tracking any of it. I fought it like crazy, but sometimes a scrummaster's opinion is just irrelevant.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about project management tools, not about programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Credit to https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/9383627/i-need-to-see-the-total-story-points-per-user-in-the-sprint- for the answer

> If you look at your sprints in plan mode, you see the people that are assigned work in that sprint just below the sprint start and end date. To the right of the people, you see 3 dots, which when clicked will open a summary showing every assignee and the number of issues and associated story points assigned to them.

Comment: Good answer. I can't believe the struggle I had in finding that. Now I can at least find it. Do you know if there is some way to put that information into a JIRA gadget?